# How to check constraint on absolute time to terminate process without affecting simulation performance?

Tags: modelica

I want to read the current date and if the date is outside a constraint then the system should be terminated. The code below works.

```
    import Modelica.Utilities.System.getTime; 
    model M
       Integer[7] today;
       constant Integer[7] limit={0,0,0,0,0,0,2021};
       Real x;
    equation
       today = getTime();
       if today[7] > limit[7] then
          terminate();
       end if;
       // Process
       x = 1;
    end M;
```

But it would be much better to just read the date at startup and avoid check the date all the time which should be a burden although not obvious from running the code above.

Most logical would be an initial algorithmic (or equation) section to get the date with getTime() and also terminate() if appropriate.

But just change the current section to "initial equation" gives compilation error with the error text: "...The following variables(s) could not be matched to any equation: today[1], .... today[7]."

Comment: You could declare `today` as a parameter with `fixed=false` and assign `getTime()` to it in an `initial equation` section. Then it would only be calculated during initialization.

Comment: The code does not work in Dymola 2021x using Modelica 4.0.0. terminate() requires a string as argument and getTime returns multiple values instead of a vector.

Comment: For MSL4, also read this ticket: https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaStandardLibrary/issues/3143

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `today` in the model so you could just move this to a function:

```
import Modelica.Utilities.System.getTime; 

function afterLimit
  input Integer limit[7];
  output Boolean after;
protected
  Integer[7] today;
algorithm
  (,,,,,,today[7]) := getTime();
  after := today[7]>limit[7];
end afterLimit;

model M
  constant Integer[7] limit={0,0,0,0,0,0,2021};
  Real x;
initial equation
  if afterLimit(limit) then
    terminate("Time is up!");
  end if;
equation
  // Process
  x = 1;
end M;
```

Alternatively you could make it a parameter with `fixed=false` as suggested by @ReneJustNielsen

Comment: With the small adjustments Marco mentions above your code works well in OpenModelica. I just wonder if it is not better/logical to say initial algorithm instead of initial equation? After all here is no equation in this part. In OpenModelica initial algorithm works as well.

Comment: I generally use equation and initial equation when possible.